# Unable to read data from kafka using GCP Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I want to read data from kafka Topic through GCP Cloud Function, for which am importing below packeges

Imports inside my main.py file

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from confluent_avro import AvroKeyValueSerde, SchemaRegistry
from confluent_avro.schema_registry import HTTPBasicAuth`
```

my requiremnts.txt file

```
kafka-python
pandas
confluent_avro
requests
```

But my test my cloud Function code it give me below error
Error:

```
from confluent_avro import AvroKeyValueSerde, SchemaRegistry
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/confluent_avro/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from confluent_avro.schema_registry import SchemaRegistry
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/confluent_avro/schema_registry/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from confluent_avro.schema_registry import auth, client_http
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/confluent_avro/schema_registry/client_http.py", line 29, in <module>
    RETRY_POLICY = SchemaRegistryRetry(
TypeError: Retry.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method_whitelist'"
```

**Can somone please suggest what I am mssing here ? **

I tried with

```
confluent_avro
confluent_avro~=1.8.0
confluent-avero
```

but they all are giving me same error.

Comment: Is there a specific reason youre using `kafka-python` and not Confluent's Python consumer module?

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually comes from the latest `urllib3` version `2.0.0` (2023-04-26) that removes `Retry` options `method_whitelist`: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/2086

One solution for you is to force urllib3 to latest `1.26.x` (on 31/05/2023 the latest is `urllib3==1.26.16`)